# How do I turn off Safari's bookmark bar shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, safari

How do I disable the <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, etc. keyboard shortcuts for bookmarks in the bookmarks bar in Safari 5?

Comment: Do you mean the shortcuts like ⌘1 for opening bookmarks on the bookmarks bar or shortcuts like ⌘D?

Comment: @Lri Yes he does, see original question revision.

Answer (score 0):

You can add nine bookmarks to the front of the bookmarks bar that point to the following:

```
javascript:void(null)
```

Give then a non-breaking space (<kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) as name. It will shift the rest of the bookmarks to the right, but pressing the shortcuts will not do anything.

[image]